# Firebase TOO_BIG error

Tags: firebase

Firebase raises a TOO_BIG error even though I'm querying by limits:

```
ref.limitToFirst(10).once('value', function(snap) {
    console.log('done', snap.numChildren());
}, function(err) {
    console.error('error', err);
});
```

Why?

**Update**

The ref var has only leafs, I guess more than 100.000, like this:

```
{   
  ".priority" : 1.413054290808E12,
  "cached" : false,   
  "meta" : "v0.9.1",   
  "obcId" : "-JI-wXp4jAKBL3p22rQM",   
  "position" : {
    "alt" : 0,
    "lat" : -6.890853404998779,
    "lng" : -68.14022827148438,
    "speed" : 42.2,
    "timestamp" : 1413072289000   
  },   
  "score" : 0,   
  "timestamp" : 1413054290808,   
  "truckId" : "-J8DKz4r6FmgqtswqhQ1" 
}
```

Comment: The client-side library gives this reason for that error code: "The data requested exceeds the maximum size that can be accessed with a single request". Are you maybe requesting data too high in your JSON tree? It may just be 10 items, but if each item is 1MB... I can imagine (but don't **know**) that Firebase has a limit on the total size.

Comment: It would definitely help if you can provide more information. I regularly run code snippets like the one you provided without any problem, so clearly the code alone is not the issue. Can you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle/jsbin/plunker/codepen?

Comment: Please, check my update. As you can see it's anything but heavy.

Comment: OK. But again... the code seems fine too. That leaves a reproduction in a jsfiddle or something like that. If you're worried about sharing your Firebase's URL, you can set up a separate Firebase just for this issue and delete it afterwards.

Comment: Aside from creating a fiddle, you should also add the code that creates the `ref`. If you're ordering the data by a child `orderByChild` then it's crucial that you define an `.indexOn` for that child. Otherwise Firebase's client will download all data and filter client-side, which is a bad idea. Note that it will log a warning if it does this client-side filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Today works! I can imagine that was just a temporary firebase issue because I run the same code on the same data set.